# How can i convert excel file of format .xlsx to .xls in Java 1.3?

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, file-conversion

I am trying to convert an excel file of .xlsx format to .xls format. I am using Java 1.3. Apache POI does not support below Java 1.4. Is there any way to convert it?

Comment: That version of Java was released around 17 years back, even before *.xlsx, If its a legacy application you could instead write a conversion util using newer Java version and try to call this application.

Comment: [Java 1.3 end-of-life was 11/12/2006](https://blogs.oracle.com/stevenChan/entry/understanding_j2se_13_endoflif). You might want to consider using a more recent version of java

Comment: Since those are Microsoft file formats, I would skip Java and see if I could find Microsoft tools for the job. Perhaps even an Excel macro? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

The file formats for xls and xlsx are completely different. xlsx was introduced with Excel 2007 and is basically a zip file with a different extension, and all the files in the Zip are xml based components.

Many Excel file tools out there still seem to handle only the old xls format.

You can use Excel to save an xlsx file in the legacy xls format, but I doubt that the older file tools have the capability to convert the newer file format to the older one.

A better approach might be to use tools that understand the xlsx format, which has been around for 10 years now.